# Ошибка при выводе шифрования столбца таблицы при помощи AES шифрования и кодировке BASE 64 от имени пользователя

Tags: mysql

При работе с таблицей от имени пользователя шифрую и кодирую записи таблицы, при этом все хорошо выводит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дешифровка тоже все выдает правильно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если пытаться выводить дешифрование и декодировку в обращении к таблице, то английский текст нормально выводится, а русский "ломается"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица была создана самим пользователем, у пользователя есть все права, даже давали права как у пользователя root, но ничего не помогает. И данной проблемы нет, когда подобное обращение идет от имени root. 
Подскажите, как это исправить

---

Но следующий вопрос, почему при сквозном прогоне BASE64 от имени root все нормально, но от имени пользователя - нет? 
Вот от имени пользователя root

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот что от имени созданного пользователя

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да с кодировочками проблемы. `SET NAMES` должно помочь...

Comment: Причем судя по скриншоту SET NAMES cp-866(по крайней мере то что у вас сейчас в БД очень похоже на CP-1251 отображенную как CP-866)
Еще, можете попробовать ввести chcp 1251 перед тем как заходить в утилиту mysql